# Google analytics Page title and Screen name clarifications

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I enabled google analytics to my flutter project. I also added the analytics observer to MyApp section. The screen related data which is logging in the analytics dashboard are like the image attached with it. I am confused with data which I am getting 1. /home 2. All Screen-Home(set by self) another 3. (not set). I just wanted to know why the data /home and not set are appearing. How to made the /home as All Screen-Home and how to set the not set data?

[image]

Wanted to know more about it from some experienced expert.

Comment: Show your code on how you are posting data to analytics. In general, in '/home' you are using namedRoutes and in "All Screen-Home" you are probably just setting the name like that

Comment: Hi I am calling screen_view event in each build method of screen class and for navigation I am doing Get.toNamed(AppPages.PAGE_NAME)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase apps will automatically [log the class name](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews) of the UIViewController or Activity that is currently in focus. You might have set an Activity or the UIViewController with "/home". Where for "All Screen-Home", you're [manually logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#manually_track_screens) it in your app.

On the other hand, you will get a (not set) value in screen reporting if you are passing the screen name when the activity/fragment is not in a proper state or when you try to set the screen name before an Activity is presented. As such, (not set) is a placeholder that Google Analytics uses when it matches this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Can you please help me how to avoid not set state.I am calling screen_view event in each build method of screen class and for navigation I am doing Get.toNamed(AppPages.PAGE_NAME). Is that right what I am doing?